# Achieve Partial wakelock inside asyncTask Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-wake-lock

I have an application that runs a long process. I am using AsyncTask class to achieve it. But when the phone sleeps the async task automatically stops. 
To stop this behaviour I want to achieve a partial wakelock when the doInBackgound starts and release it when it ends.

But when I paste the following code in doInBackground method, the getSystemService gives the error that it is undefined for the type myclass.

```
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

Can you gimme a workaround for this..

What I want to do is..

```
class doit extends AsyncTask<String, String , Void>
{
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
{
//Achieve Partial Wakelock
//Do long Work
//Release Lock
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414588/android-context-and-context-powermanager

Comment: I have no way to test it right now, so this is more of a guess than anything (hence a comment instead of an answer):  Try `(PowerManager)<parent class>.this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)`

Comment: @Simon That is unrelated, since this is all about accessing a Context instance inside an AsyncTask

Comment: why not to achieve wakelock in `onPreExecute` method and release it in `onPostExecute`. If you declare your AsyncTask subclass inside an activity as static class, you really need to pass Context parameter in constructor of your class. But if your class is non-static you have an implicit access to the activity class and can call `getSystemService`

Comment: You should grab the wake lock in the constructor as the device may go to sleep before it gets to onPreExecute.

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor and pass Context object from the activity

```
Context context;
doit(Context mContext){
    super();
    context = mContext;
}
```

Then use

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

Will not work because `getSystemService()` is not a method of `AsyncTask`. You need to pass your applications `Context` object to your `AsyncTask` and then do the following since `getSystemService()` is a function of `Context`.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```